# « composer avec », « gérer » ou « enclin à »?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation, reformulation

1-Pour être médecin, il faut savoir composer avec le complexe de culpabilité, le mieux serait de le réprimer totalement.

2-Pour être médecin, il faut savoir gérer le complexe de culpabilité, idéalement il faudrait le reléguer dans l’ombre de la conscience.

3-Pour être médecin, il vaut mieux ne pas être enclin au complexe de culpabilité.

D’autres tournures à suggérer?

Comment: Si j'étais toi, je ne parlerais pas de "complexe de" culpabilité. Le mot culpabilité tout seul suffit. Les gens peuvent se sentir coupable d'un truc sans avoir un complexe. Les médicins doivent bien gérer leurs émotions.

Comment: Un simple sentiment de culpabilité n'est pas la même chose qu'un _sentiment de culpabilité hypertrophié au point de devenir morbide_,(TLFi), le _complexe_ ; il y a une question de degré et de pathologie. Chose certaine, l'un ne signifie pas l'autre.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

La première phrase  est suffisamment expressive.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/composer))  **B**.− Emploi intrans. Composer (éventuellement suivi de : avec qqn ou qqc.).Faire un effort pour arriver à une entente avec quelqu'un en faisant des concessions.
> − P. ext. Composer avec sa conscience, ses préjugés, ses principes; composer avec le mal, le vice. Synon. biaiser, accepter des demi-mesures, se compromettre
> ♦ Il [Bréauté] composait avec sa conscience ombrageuse et facilement bourrelée pour transformer cette tendresse en paternité... L. Daudet, La Mésentente,1911, p. 264.

La seconde me semble artificielle, le verbe à tout faire « gérer » ne semble pas être un heureux choix. On peut même penser qu'il est question d'entretenir ce complexe de culpabilité, de le choyer.

La troisième est d'un tout autre ordre de considérations que la première ; ce n'est plus l'assertion de la nécessité d'un modus vivendi, mais celle de la nécessité d'une condition préliminaire ; il reste à savoir si  « *être enclin à un complexe*  » est une réalité psychologique. À mon avis  soit on est affecté par un complexe soit on ne l'est pas ; ce mal peut être plus ou moins intense, mais il semble que l'on ne puisse jamais en être libéré ; une affectation sporadique est peut-être possibilité en ce qui concerne ces « maux » psychologiques.

Contribuer des tournures alternatives doit être compris, je le suppose, comme fournir des tournures qui sont des paraphrases de ces trois modèles, et non des tournure selon le principe d'ajouter une tournure de plus au tout hétéroclite que forment ces trois exemples.

Comme il me semble ne  pouvoir me pencher que sur l'idée de la première phrase, c'est sur celle-là que sont basée les trois tournures ci-dessus.

- Pour être médecin, il faut savoir mitiger  le complexe de culpabilité par une bonne dose de sens du devoir, le mieux serait de le réprimer totalement.
- Pour être médecin, il faut savoir se rendre imperméable au  complexe de culpabilité, le mieux serait de le réprimer totalement.
- Pour être médecin, il faut comprendre qu'un  complexe de culpabilité va à l'encontre du devoir et il faut combattre cette tendance à s'immerger dans les sentiments de faute ; le mieux serait de pouvoir le réprimer totalement.